# Jmeter, How to get one of response result to assign to next request

Tags: jmeter, response, extract

I have a response for **request** #1: 2 step codes that correspond with stepId as below. 
In next request, I want to use only stepId = stepId that I assign from CSV file

```
**content**":[
            {
                "stepId":21,
                "stepCode":"11",
                "stepName":"11",

            },
            {
                "stepId":17,
                "stepCode":"??",
                "stepName":"To be checked",

            }
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For example if you need to get `stepCode` value where `stepId` is `17` you can use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and the following JSON Path query:

```
$..[?(@.stepId == '17')].stepCode
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSON Path Conditional Select]

You can replace this `17` with a variable coming from the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) like:

```
$..[?(@.stepId == '${your_variable_from_csv}')].stepCode
```

References:

- [Json Path Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)